# Send start and end date in requestmapping in rest controller in spring boot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

i am fetching data from multiple tables in spring boot using hibernate jpa.
My query is perfect and working fine, I am just stuck in how to pass start and date from rest controller and call in URL.
Here is my rest controller code:

```
@RequestMapping("/employeeMonthlyAttendance/startDate/{startDate}/endDate/{endDate}")
public String generateEmployeeMonthlyAttendanceReport(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable Date startDate, @PathVariable Date endDate){

    try {
        System.out.println("METHOD CALLED");

        List<EmployeeMonthlyAttendanceReport> employees = employeeMonthlyAttendanceReportService.getEmployeeMonthlyAttendance(startDate, endDate) ;

        // Get your data source
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource jrBeanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(employees);

        // Add parameters
//            Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();


        JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;

        //For Download PDF File
//            response.setContentType("application/x-download");
//            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",   String.format("attachment; filename=\"All Sections Employees.pdf\""));

        //For  Direct View PDF FILE
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("inline; filename=\"Employees Monthly Attendance Report.pdf\""));

        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        jasperPrint = jasperReportService.exportPDFFileWithData("EmployeeMonthlyAttendanceReport", new HashedMap(), jrBeanCollectionDataSource);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, out);

        System.out.println("Done");

        return "Report successfully generated";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Error--> check the console log";
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you please share the data format you're looking forward to use?

For example: dd-MM-yyyy

Comment: yyyy-MM-dd this will be the formate of date

Comment: What my understanding is that you want to call this REST endpoint `/employeeMonthlyAttendance/startDate/{startDate}/endDate/{endDate}` and need a format to pass in the {startDate} and {endDate}, right?

Comment: @Safeer Ansari  no i want to call url with date parameters in rest controller

Comment: What URL are you going to call, and where is the code required to call the URL?

Comment: http://localhost:9999/reports/employees/employeeMonthlyAttendance/startDate=2019-07-01/endDate=2019-07-31
like that how i can send this date

Comment: That's exactly what I am talking about.
You're willing to call this endpoint employees/employeeMonthlyAttendance/startDate/{startDate}/endDate/{endDate}

You cannot call the endpoint having path params using query params.
Your URL endpoint should look like this `http://localhost:9999/reports/employees/employeeMonthlyAttendance/startDate=/2019-07-01/endDate/2019-07-31`

Comment: yes but its giving 404 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @PathVariable("startDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
>   Date startDate @PathVariable("endDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern =
>   "yyyy-MM-dd") Date endDate

Try making these changes in generateEmployeeMonthlyAttendanceReport() method. Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to add DateTimeFormat in your method parameter by adding `import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat` in the imports section of your rest controller.

Your controller method would look like:

```
    @RequestMapping("/employeeMonthlyAttendance/startDate/{startDate}/endDate/{endDate}")
        public String generateEmployeeMonthlyAttendanceReport(HttpServletResponse response, 
        @PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date startDate, @PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date endDate){
        }
```

Now you can call your endpoint from any REST client by passing a formatted date.

Your URL would look like:
http://localhost:9999/reports/employees/employeeMonthlyAttendance/startDate/2019-07-01/endDate/2019-07-31

I hope this is what you're looking for